# How to test ios app from flutter in Windows

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am a beginner in flutter development. I have heard that ios app can make and test only in Mac. I don't know it's wrong or not.

But now I am started learning Flutter in Windows. I don't have enough money to buy a Mac. So is there any problem with learning flutter in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Mac to build and test for iOS.

There are workarounds though. You could use a tool like Appollo. Appollo is a CLI utility that let's you:

- configure Xcode
- Test on an iOS simulator
- Build an IPA, to install on a physical device
- or build and publish your app in the App Store

Here is a link to their [github](https://github.com/Appollo-CLI/Appollo) and [documentation](https://appollo.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can learn flutter on windows and publish android apps or for the web.
however, for developing ios apps, mac is required.
the codebase remains the same, so there is no rework.
you can use https://codemagic.io/ for ios builds.

Comment: I am a beginner in English too... so that means, The same code will work on both Android and ios. There is no need for testing in both devices.

Comment: Just copy the code used in android and paste into ios will work?